# Image not going to the most-right of website

Tags: html, css

I am using float right for an image that I am trying for it to go to the most right part of my screen but there is still a big gap between my image and the right most part of my screen. Anyone know why?

```css
.Sideways {
  float: right;
  margin: 10px 0 0 0;
  max-width: 25%;
}
```

```html
<img src="Myself.jpg" alt="A picture of myself" class="Sideways">
<p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet consectetur adipisicing elit. Exercitationem inventore autem expedita quas, perspiciatis eum temporibus quae? Rem amet numquam itaque dolor porro nostrum repellat? Quaerat corrupti quod, illo laboriosam aliquam dicta cumqueillum, libero sapiente molestias ut, assumenda nemo sint placeat! Iste molestiae mollitia nihil magni asperiores libero vitae.</p>
```

Comment: Your code actually placing the image to the right.

Answer (score 0):

This sounds like it could be the default margin on your page's `body`... in your CSS try adding the following:

```
body {
  margin: 0;
}
```

Comment: That did not do anything

Comment: Here it is running in a fiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/cjoz4pn0/. Do you have __any__ other HTML elements or __any__ other CSS declarations?

Comment: I only have a typical ul with a home, about, etc buttons in the top of my website (displaying in line).

Comment: Without more details (jsfiddle or pastebin) and/or an image of the problem, not sure I can help.

Comment: Ok, sorry. Change of plans now but still a question: my h3 with the text ShinDor Soccer will not be correctly centered and I am confused as to why. I found out that if I comment my code on CSS where I make my navigations button float to the right, then the h3 would be correctly centered. However not sure how float right would affect this. The link is: https://jsfiddle.net/pyc4jnxw/.

Comment: Never mind I figured it out, thanks for the help though!